# Update event end (updateEvent)

Tags: fullcalendar

Create an event parameter `allDay = true` (`end = null`). And then using the `updateEvent` method changing the end time of the event. All good, but the end time is saved with less 12 hours (time zone). How can I fix this?

With the start time of the event this doesn't happen.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  Please read this guide for asking a good question here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. Now I will consider.

With the problem figured out. In the properties fullcalendar installed " 'timezone':'local'". Somehow a method of "updateEvent" transforms the end time (the start time does not change) events to UTC time.

So now clearly indicate the start and end times of the event:

```
moment.parseZone("2017-10-05T17:00").utc().format()
```

or

```
moment.parseZone("2017-10-05T17:00").local().format()
```

Comment: Please accept your answer if it is correct, so you help future visitors who have the same problem.